# Reading a text file with multiple data entries and converting them into an object and stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object

I am uploading a file that has multiple DNA sequence ID's followed by their DNA sequences. I would like to be able to parse the file and store the information in an object:

```
function scanForSequences(event) {
    //Get the file from HTML input tag
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var output = document.getElementById('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');

    if(file) {
        var sequenceArray = [];
        var objArray = [];
        var obj = {};


        //Create a new file reader
        var reader = new FileReader();
        //When the file reader loads
        reader.onload = function(evt) {
            //Add the contents of file to variable contents
            var contentsByLine = evt.target.result.split('\n');
            //Alert user the file upload has succeeded
            alert('File ' + file.name + ' has been uploaded!');

            for(var i = 0; i < contentsByLine.length; i++){
                if(contentsByLine[i].charAt(i) == '>'){
                    obj.id = contentsByLine[i];
                }else{
                    sequenceArray.push(contentsByLine[i]);
                    obj.sequence = sequenceArray;
                    obj.lead_trim = 0;
                    obj.trail_trim = 0;
                }
                objArray.push({obj});
                console.log(objArray);
                //console.log(sequenceArray[i].length);
            }

        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    } else {
        alert('Failed to upload file!');
    }
}
```

The problem is that only the first sequence ID is recognized and the rest of the info just gets push into my sequenceArray. Can anyone help me figure out my mistake here? I appreciate it!

Here is the text file:

>9013e1
ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCC
CCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGC
CTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGG
AAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCC
CTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAG
TTTAATTACAGACCTGAA

>9042f1
ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCC
CCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGC
CTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGG
AAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCC
CTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAG
TTTAATTACAGACCTGAA

Comment: Can you provide some sample input? It appears that you are looking for a '>' in different places on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are looking for, but this function should parse the text into objects in an array. Hopefully you can modify it to get what you need. With some editing, you should be able to use it as your `reader.onload` function.

What I fixed:

- In your code, you were checking the 'i'th character instead of the first character of each line
- You were adding the same sequence array to all your objects so every id would end up with all the sequences attached to it
- You weren't creating a new object for each entry so essentially you were pushing the same object into the array multiple times

```js
function parse(fileContents) {
  //Add the contents of file to variable contents
  var contentsByLine = fileContents.split('\n'),
      objArray = [],
      obj;

  for(var i = 0; i < contentsByLine.length; i++){
    if(contentsByLine[i][0] == '>'){
      obj = {
        id: contentsByLine[i],
        sequence: [],
        lead_trim: 0,
        trail_trim: 0
      };
      objArray.push({obj});
    }else{
      obj.sequence.push(contentsByLine[i]);
    }
    console.log(objArray);
  }

}

parse(">9013e1\nACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCC\n>9042f1\nACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCC");
```

Comment: Awesome! That did it! Thank you for the help. :)